# PHP, MYSQLi query results not working with with WHERE using $_GET

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, global-variables

I am trying to get the results of a SQL query using WHERE, whenever I use the $_GET variable it doesn't work, now I have echoed the $query variable and it shows the value of $_GET['idced'] but for some reason it doesn't do the query thus the loop doesn't show anything.

But when I manually type in the value that I want to compare, it works perfectly fine... any help would be greatly appreciated.. I also know that their might be some security issues with using GET but its a local app so it's not a concern.. heere is the code I have:

```
 <?php

          $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "cx", "", "cxtrack");

          /* check connection */
          if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
            } 


          $idced_history = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['idced']);

          //This is the query that is not working:
          $query = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE idced = $idced_history;";


        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

         //This loop works fine when I replace $idced_history with a value of idced
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $curenttime=$row["applicationposition"];
            $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);

           echo "<div style='background:red; position:relative; top:2.6em; margin-bottom:1%;'>";
           echo "<a href='#'>".$row["applicationposition"]."</a><br/>";
           echo "Applied On: ".$row["applicationdate"]." ( ". timeAgo($time_ago) ." ) <br>";
           echo "Via: ".$row["applicationtype"]."</div>";
           }

         $result->free();
       }

          $mysqli->close();
                ?>
```

Comment: You're using MySQLi, so stop escaping inputs and injecting directly into queries, and start using prepared statements with bind variables.... if you need to escape values, then they're strings, and should be quoted in queries.... using bind variables in your queries would do all this for you

Comment: Drop the trailing `;`  from the query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys but nothing worked, any other ideas?

Comment: Already mentioned in comment 1 - sort of...

If the idced column contains a string, you can try this where $idced_history is surrounded by '
characters.

$query = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE idced = '$idced_history' ";

Answer (score 1):

sometime it not work that way.. try change to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE idced = ".$idced_history;
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because, idced you get from url is a string and you should spare strings from the sql query with single quotes. Otherwise, mysql act like to your variable as a table name.

try

```
"SELECT * FROM applications WHERE idced = '$idced_history'";
```